# VS 2010: Change color of lines based on a pattern

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I change color of lines in Visual Studio 2010 based on some custom pattern? For example, I want to change color of all lines that start with `logger.` . Is it possible at all?

I have ReSharper 5 installed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up a quick little extension to do this; since you'll very likely want to modify it, you should [grab the source](http://github.com/NoahRic/Random/blob/master/HighlightMatchingLines.cs).  The important part is the code in `LayoutChanged`:

```
    void ViewLayoutChanged(object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IWpfTextView view = sender as IWpfTextView;
        var adornmentLayer = view.GetAdornmentLayer("HighlightLines");

        foreach (var line in e.NewOrReformattedLines)
        {
            if (line.Extent.GetText().StartsWith("logger.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
                    {
                        Width = view.ViewportWidth + view.MaxTextRightCoordinate,
                        Height = line.Height,
                        Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue
                    };

                Canvas.SetTop(rect, line.Top);
                Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);
                adornmentLayer.AddAdornment(line.Extent, null, rect);
            }
        }
    }
```

To build/run this, you'll need to:

1. [Download the VS2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en).
2. Create a new project from the editor extension templates (I usually pick Visual C# -> Extensibility -> Editor Text Adornment).
3. Delete all the source files it creates.
4. Add HighlightMatchingLines.cs to the project.
5. F5 to run/test.
6. If you want to change the brush, change the `Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue` line.
7. If you want to change what text is matched, changed the condition in the `if` expression.
8. If you want to change what file type the extension is loaded for, change the `[ContentType]` attribute.  The "Content Types" section of [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885244.aspx) lists out some of the common ones.

Comment: Thought about writing an extension, but didn't want to get into it. Nevertheless you are awesome!