# Change text color for specific lines based on pattern matching in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing some notes in a markdown file in VS Code and would like to see certain lines of text have their text color changed (not highlighted or background color changed).

Example:
[image: vscode]

Desired result (by example of opening the same file in **gedit**):
[image: gedit]

I would like to know if there's a plugin or customization option that fulfills my requirement.
Additionally and if possible I'd like the solution to fulfill some optional requirements:

- customize the color that is applied based on set patterns:

  - eg. apply green color to the entire line when pattern `(\t|\s)*✔.*` has been matched
  - in my specific case, I'd like to apply 4 different colors based on 4 different symbols or set of characters that should be matched: `✔`, `-->`, `⤵` and `✘`
- only apply color changes to lines based on specified file extensions:

  - eg. `.*` match all file extensions; `.md, .cs, .py` match only markdown, C# and Python files
  - in my specific case, I'd like to only match on Markdown files with the `.md` extension

A great plugin that does something similar is: https://github.com/aaron-bond/better-comments
Unfortunately this one only matches code tags within comments, and I'd like to match outside of comments as well.
Related threads: [VS 2010: Change color of lines based on a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251605/vs-2010-change-color-of-lines-based-on-a-pattern)

Comment: the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) does what you want, look at the **Basic** example, it only changes the foreground color of `property`, a possible addition would be the language id

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516484/836330 as a good example of using the Highlight extension

Comment: @Mark do you know what I'm possibly doing wrong? I posted my current configuration in an answer.

Comment: Another concern is that my laptop fans went off like crazy, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the regex matching in this case, maybe a timeout or something can be set.. or limit the scope of the search.

Comment: nvm, I think I figured it out, I'm applying the color on the wrong capture group..

Answer (score 0):

Installed [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) as suggested by [riov8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) and [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark).

I've made some changes to my configuration compared to the initial specification in the question.
This is the configuration I'm using that meets the requirements of the question and then some:

```json
"highlight.regexes": {
    "((\\s+✔.*)|(✔\\s+.*))": {
      "regexFlags": "gi",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown",
      "filterFileRegex": ".*\\.md",
      "decorations": [{"color": "#679142"}]
    },
    "((\\s+-->.*)|(-->\\s+.*))": {
      "regexFlags": "gi",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown",
      "filterFileRegex": ".*\\.md",
      "decorations": [{"color": "#FF8C00"}]
    },
    "((\\s+⤵.*)|(⤵\\s+.*))": {
      "regexFlags": "gi",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown",
      "filterFileRegex": ".*\\.md",
      "decorations": [{"color": "#569CD6"}]
    },
    "((\\s+✘.*)|(✘\\s+.*))": {
      "regexFlags": "gi",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown",
      "filterFileRegex": ".*\\.md",
      "decorations": [{"color": "#FF6464"}]
    },
```

**NOTE**: *There was an error in earlier versions of this configuration where matching on any whitespace `\\s` did not work correctly. Read comments for further elaboration on this issue.*

Here's how the color highlighting is now applied to my markdown file:

[image: results-screenshot]

Comment: I have simplified the settings, less Decorators, only 1 group per regex if all the same color

Comment: You shouldn't need both the language and file filters.  One or the other.  And the file filter would be of the form `.*\\.md` or for all the languages you mentioned: `.*\\.(md|cs|py)`.  `\\.*md` as you had would match `.blahmd` files as well as `.md` files..

Comment: `\\.*md` would also match `READMEmd` with no extension or `README.....md` - probably not your intent.

Comment: Thanks, I changed "filterFileRegex" now. I'll rather keep both of the filters on since I want to make sure that this regex matching applies only to markdown files with the `.md` extension. I'm not sure how VS Code determines the type or "Language" of a file other than probably a combination of looking at file extension, and possibly trying to statically analyze the contents of the file. Updating the answer now.

Comment: And another piece of good news, I tried replacing the tabs matching `\t` with `\\s` and it now seems to work as intended, whereas yesterday the trailing 1-3 remained uncolored! I'm unable to reproduce the bug yesterday, maybe if I apply an earlier version of this configuration. I suspect that the error occurred because I didn't split it up into two inner capture groups that are OR:ed like I'm doing now.
Updating my answer again.

Comment: The extension author is using the language id - the same thing that shows in parentheses when you click on the language, i.e., the `Markdown` button in the lower right-hand corner of vscode and then in parentheses for Markdown it will say `markdown` - that is what the extension code uses.  "Usually" the lower-cased version of the same but some are different.

Comment: Actually I would avoid the nested capture groups, the README says: `Nested capturing groups are not supported.`  I have seen them work before in simple case like yours but... Doesn't `(^\s*✔.*$)`, with an `m` flag added to `regexFlags`, not cover all your `((\\s+✔.*)|(✔\\s+.*))` use cases, for example?

Comment: I tried matching with the `/m` flag yesterday and it only captured the first matching line, color wasn't applied to subsequent lines in the file that matched the pattern. I used `^` and `$` as you mentioned to denote the beginning and end of line. I'm not gonna mess with it any more tbh, as the saying goes "don't fix it if it ain't broken". But if anything gets messed up with later versions or my fan starts to spin up like crazy I'll take another look at it. :)

Comment: You are putting the `m` flag into the `"regexFlags": "gim",` option hopefully - not into the regex itself.  It works for me fine with the simple regex wherever the text is, subsequent matches too.

Comment: no I know :D the "regexFlags" option is RIGHT THERE in the JSON object afterall, would be hard to miss.. I tried `/m` and `/gmi` yesterday, didn't work. I'll stick with `/gi` for now, hopefully it doesn't punish my CPU or anything, someone else is free to confirm whether it works or not. Thanks for the suggestion though and thanks to both you and @rioV8 for the help! :)

Comment: no need to group the alternatives `|` just `"(\\s+✔.*|✔\\s+.*)"` is enough